# Running two showDiv() functions on the same page

Tags: javascript

I'm just getting started with Javascript, and I'm trying to figure out how to distinguish between two showDiv () functions on the same page.

I want to be able to click on the "Buy" button and have one div appear or click on the "Donate" button and have another div appear. The overall goal is so a form to purchase a product will appear when the Buy button is clicked, but a form to donate will appear when the Donate button is clicked.

I understand that currently it is just running the second function and ignoring the first, so what is the best way to link up the buttons to their respective functions so both functions will work?

Here is the code:

```js
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('shirt-form').style.display = "block";
}

function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('donate-form').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
input.buy {
  color: white; 
  background:#a50b0b;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; 
  font-family: 'Cairo',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

input.buy:hover {
  background-color: rgb(74, 109, 130) !important;
}

input.donate {
  color: white; 
  background:#a50b0b;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; 
  font-family: 'Cairo',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

input.donate:hover {
  background-color: rgb(74, 109, 130) !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="buy" type="button" name="answer" value="Buy" onclick="showDiv()" />
<div id="shirt-form"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > BUY </div>

<br><br>

<input class="donate" type="button" name="answer" value="Donate" onclick="showDiv()" />
<div id="donate-form"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > DONATE </div>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Always use different function names for different functions or you'll overwrite the other. Also consider attaching handlers properly using Javascript rather than inline attributes, which are as bad as `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change one of the function names, they should be named differently so the bottom one doesn't override the top function definition.

```
function showDivShirt() {
    document.getElementById('shirt-form').style.display = "block";
}

function showDivDonate() {
    document.getElementById('donate-form').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to keep one function and pass the element id as the argument

```js
function showDiv(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
input.buy {
  color: white; 
  background:#a50b0b;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; 
  font-family: 'Cairo',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

input.buy:hover {
  background-color: rgb(74, 109, 130) !important;
}

input.donate {
  color: white; 
  background:#a50b0b;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; 
  font-family: 'Cairo',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

input.donate:hover {
  background-color: rgb(74, 109, 130) !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="buy" type="button" name="answer" value="Buy" onclick="showDiv('shirt-form')" />
<div id="shirt-form"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > BUY </div>

<br><br>

<input class="donate" type="button" name="answer" value="Donate" onclick="showDiv('donate-form')" />
<div id="donate-form"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > DONATE </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need multiple functions. Just pass corresponding `id` to the function call:

```js
function showDiv(elId) {
   document.getElementById(elId).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
input.buy {
  color: white; 
  background:#a50b0b;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; 
  font-family: 'Cairo',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

input.buy:hover {
  background-color: rgb(74, 109, 130) !important;
}

input.donate {
  color: white; 
  background:#a50b0b;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; 
  font-family: 'Cairo',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

input.donate:hover {
  background-color: rgb(74, 109, 130) !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="buy" type="button" name="answer" value="Buy" onclick="showDiv('shirt-form')" />
<div id="shirt-form"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > BUY </div>

<br><br>

<input class="donate" type="button" name="answer" value="Donate" onclick="showDiv('donate-form')" />
<div id="donate-form"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > DONATE </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give two different function name.

```js
function showShirtDiv() {
   document.getElementById('shirt-form').style.display = "block";
}

function showDonateDiv() {
   document.getElementById('donate-form').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
input.buy {
  color: white; 
  background:#a50b0b;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; 
  font-family: 'Cairo',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

input.buy:hover {
  background-color: rgb(74, 109, 130) !important;
}

input.donate {
  color: white; 
  background:#a50b0b;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; 
  font-family: 'Cairo',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}

input.donate:hover {
  background-color: rgb(74, 109, 130) !important;
}
```

```html
<input class="buy" type="button" name="answer" value="Buy" onclick="showShirtDiv()" />
<div id="shirt-form"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > BUY </div>

<br><br>

<input class="donate" type="button" name="answer" value="Donate" onclick="showDonateDiv()" />
<div id="donate-form"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > DONATE </div>
```